# How to have a unit/integration/functional pipeline in a single Gradle test execution

Tags: java, gradle

I have a demo project that uses springboot and can setup a full server in JUnit tests: https://github.com/paul-hammant/todo-backend-spring4-java8. Gradle is fast anyway, but the build here pulls in WebDriver and it is still fast (20 seconds), which I why I made the demo.

I only have a single WebDriver test class now (with three test methods). I am going to add pure unit tests (no threads, no IO) and integration tests (does do IO, but no UIs though).

I want to configure a test execution that does unit tests, then integration tests, then functional tests. Yes, in a specific order, as is implied by 'the test pyramid' and called out specifically in all the documentation surrounding continuous delivery pipelines.

I would also want an opportunity to fail at each of those transitions. Meaning no need to run the WebDriver/functional tests if the unit or integrations tests fail.

**How to configure pipeline stages in Gradle, with fast fail, and what annotations to use?**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a continuous integration tool like Jenkins then you need to have separate build jobs in a pipeline for unit, integration and functional tests and make them run in sequence on the condition that the previous job was successful. All of them can be run separately using their own gradle tasks. For example:

```
./gradlew test
./gradlew integrationTest
./gradlew functionalTest
```

This way you will have more visibility for the point of failure. Each job can execute one or more than one test depending on your scenario.

But if you want a single command to execute all of the tasks then wrap them in another gradle task. Keeep in mind that it will reduce visibility drastically.